# Grid Voltage Ride Through using PSSE

Tags: inverter, power-engineering, power-grid

I am trying to simulate a low voltage ride through (LVRT) lagging case (Qgenerator = max). The inverter seems to be going to momentary cessation, and although the output power at the inverter terminals is 0, the power at the infinite bus is not 0. Is this something related to the PSSE simulator, or is there some theory that I am missing?

I will attach screenshots of the plots as reference, and in case you need anything else please let me know.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: inverter output power during LVRT]

[image: the circled area should be 0?]

[image: Sing]

[image: Voltage at inverter]

[image: voltage at infinite bus]

[image: reactive power at inverter]

[image: reactive power at infinite bus]

Comment: I think more information is needed. How about a 1-line of the model? What events are happening in your simulation?

Comment: @pdb5627 thank you for the reply. I edited the post so that it includes more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand what is happening in your model, but from what I see, although the active power output of the BES GEN1 bus is zero while the voltage is depressed, the reactive power shown in your "Page 3" plot is substantially greater than zero. Could the active power you see flowing from the POI bus toward the BES during the voltage depression be to supply the active power losses resulting from the  reactive power injection from the BES? I see there is also a load on the SUB_S bus. Both of these seem small compared to the value of power shown in your plot with the blue circle, so I'm not sure if this fully explains your results. You could test these theories by setting resistance in your transformers to zero (the lines already look lossless?) and taking that load out of service and see how it looks for each of those changes separately and then combined.